# Steam games lagging on Debian 7

Tags: debian, performance, steam

I installed Steam on to my ThinkPad laptop which is running Debian 7. It has a Intel Core 2 Duo P8600 @ 2.40Ghz and 4GB RAM, along with an Intel Mobile 4 Series graphics card. It's my understanding that this is integrated.

I've two games on my Steam account, Football Manager 2014 and Kerbal Space Program. Both of these games are quite laggy, with Kerbal being the worst offender. It's incredibly laggy at all aspects of the game, except for the main menu!

I've turned down all the graphics so that it's as basic as it can be, but it doesn't seem to make one bit of difference to the game, it still lags.

What can I do to improve the performance of Steam on Debian?

Comment: Chances are it's probably the Integrated Graphics slowing things down. The System Requirements for KSP aren't very specific, except 512MB Video Card with Shader Model 3. 512MB is quite a bit when it coems to integrated graphics.

Comment: So your card support Hardware Acceleration? You can check using `glxinfo | grep render`. Paste that in your question.

Comment: @Braiam I've just checked with that command and yes it does. It supports direct rendering.

Comment: Could you paste that in your question?

Comment: Another possible bottleneck is the use of memory. Can you post, while you are playing, the output of free -m?